# What is a parametrised select? PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

We need to add a parameterised select in a pl/sql function. But I don't know what is a parameterised select. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably talking about using bind variables in SQL statement in a PL/SQL code, like this:

```
declare
anumb     number:=1;
.....
begin
   select ....
   into ....
   from your_table
   where a_column=anumb .....;
   ....
end;
```

In this sample code, the select can be called 'parameterised', as is uses a variable set before in the SQL. 'anumb' can also be a parameter passed to a function or procedure.
Finally, why do you tag your quest with sql-server when you have PL/SQL in the subject?